# How to get headers into framework in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, frameworks

I'm trying to build a framework for MacOS in Xcode 3. It looks like it's building everything except the Headers directory according to the layout listed in the Apple documentation. I can't find anything that tells me what settings to use to get the build process to copy the headers into Headers directory in the framework, or alternately where I have to put those files.

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The headers need to be made "public" instead of the default "project" in the framework target (select the framework target in the Files & Groups pane to list the framework files).

Comment: Thanks. That answered the question that I asked. But for some reason, the application project isn't able to find the .h file. I've got #import <imSimReal/imSimReal.h> but it's not being found. I've gotten the framework added to the project frameworks, added the path to the framework into the header search paths, but no joy...

Comment: Is the framework also added to the target's "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase? If the framework is added to the target's link binary with libraries phase, the header search paths should be configured automatically.

Comment: How do I make the headers "public" ?  Can't seem to find the option in XCode 3.2.3

Comment: Select the framework's target in the "Targets" group. In the file listing for the target, there's a "Public|Private" popup for each header.

Comment: Damn ! You saved me big time. This is so porly documented and hidden in Xcode. I was getting crazy !

Comment: Under XCode 4.2.1, click the header file in the Project Navigator, then menu View/Utilities/Show File Inspector. On the right, in the File Inspector, Under Target Membership, change setting from Project to Public. Now your framework (in that weird location) will include the header files under a new Headers Directory. XCode 4.2.1 has so many settings it's often very hard to find them!

Comment: To see whether it has worked, after changing your header files to public, rebuild your framework, double-click on the .dmg file to open it as a drive, then right-click on the framework file in the Finder window and select Show Package Contents. Look in the Headers folder inside the package.

If the header files are NOT there, you can fix the problem by deleting the cached data for your project: open the Organizer from the Window menu, click on the Projects icon, then press the Delete button to the right of the line starting "Derived Data" for your project, then rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add the path to the framework to the framework search path, not the header search path.